# How to query All devices with status None in axl?

Tags: cisco, cucm, cisco-axl

Currently i am trying to use AXL to query Phone status.

I am building python web application to query status of phone in call manager.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/"
xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns2:Body>
<ns1:SelectCmDevice>
    <CmSelectionCriteria xsi:type="ns1:CmSelectionCriteria">
        <Class xsi:type="tns:DeviceClass">Phone</Class>
        <ns1:SelectBy xsi:type="ns3:string">Name</ns1:SelectBy>
    </CmSelectionCriteria>
</ns1:SelectCmDevice>
</ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am expecting it to give all Phones. But it's not giving Phones with Status as None.

Please point me to right documentation to query devices with None Status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUCM Risport SOAP service will contain data only for devices that have registered with CUCM at some point since the last CUCM restart (and within the last ~48hrs) - devices which have never registered will not appear.

You may need to use the CUCM AXL SOAP API (i.e. `<listPhone>` ) to get a full listing of configured devices, then compare with what you get back from Risport SOAP to determine the never-registered devices.